# How to override CTRL-O in Internet Explorer with GWT?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, gwt, gxt

I'm using GWT and want to use the keyboard shortcut CTRL-O to fire an event. The default browser behavior should not be shown. In Firefox and Chrome this works. But in Internet Explorer, the event is fired but after that, the IE wants to open a document.

Code:

```java
Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new NativePreviewHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event) {
        final int eventType = event.getTypeInt();
        if (eventType == Event.ONKEYDOWN) {
            NativeEvent ne = event.getNativeEvent();
            if (79 == ne.getKeyCode() && ne.getCtrlKey()) {
                Window.alert("Fired!");
            }
            ne.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: could you also post the IE version(s) you want to support?

Comment: IE version is 10. 9 would be also good.